# How to bootstrap SpringBoot application (without mvc)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to use spring-data & IOC container for some test app.

And the problem is: how to bootstrap the app?
In case of spring-mvc we move from controllers, but how to do this without mvc?

I need some main-like method for my code, but the application `public static void main` is already used for spring initialization:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

So, where should I place my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `CommandLineRunner` interface that just means to do that.

```
@Service
class FooBar implements CommandLineRunner {

    // Inject whatever collaborator you need

    @Override
    void run(String... args) throws Exception {
      // Execute whatever you need. 
      // command-line arguments are available if you need them
    }
}
```

Comment: Or the `ApplicationRunner` with easier access to the command line arguments, if you use Spring Boot >= 1.3.0